# Найти отличное от других число

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть последовательность различных `int` чисел. Необходимо эффективно найти любое `int` число, отличающееся от данных. Считаем, что такое число существует.

Comment: Для последовательности, о котрой большне ничего не известно, не существует и не может существовать алгоритма, более эффективного, чем `O(n)`. Алгоритмы же за `O(n)` - тривиальны. Возникает закономерный вопрос: какой "эффективности" ожидал автор? И если речь идет о `O(n)`, то зачем нужен вопорос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Находим максимальное, прибавляем 1. `O(n)`.

```
int x = max_element(begin(array),end(array));
```

Минус - теоретически возможно, что в массиве есть одновременно минимальное/максимальное представимые значения...

Если структура отсортированная - сразу смотрим минимальное/максимальное значения, если они не минимальное/максимальное представимые - берем на 1 меньше (соответственно, больше), итого - `O(1)`.

Если они минимальное/максимальное представимые - идем до первого "просвета", берем его. `O(n)`.

В общем случае меньше чем за `O(n)` не вижу вариантов...

Comment: ... и получаем переполнение.

Comment: вообще говоря, данные можно закинуть в любую структуру, а не только массив, так что желательно logn

Comment: См. дополнение к ответу.

Comment: @generator:  Само "закидывание" займет `O(n)`..`O(n log n)` времени. Смысл?

Comment: @AnT представление данных не входит в алгоритм, они даются "как есть" в удобной структуре, т.е. сложность добавления можно не учитывать

Comment: @generator: Чего???! Где у в вопросе сказано, что данные "даются в удобной структуре"? Почему эта критически важная информация, переворачивающая всю суть задачи, не указана в тексте вопроса? (Вопрос не риторитческий - ответ обязателен.)

Comment: @AnT полностью согласен. Чисто теоретически, я часто пользовался самописным сетом, с функцией получить 1 элемент не принадлежащему сету (Шпрага-Гранди надо было...), поэтому ответ может быть "1 операция, получить это число".